# how it get return Optional<List<VO>> from mybatis

Tags: java, spring, java-8, mybatis

I'm not an English speaker.

coz English is not fluent.

I wanna use Optional in Mapper

like this

```
public interface TestMapper {
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    Optional<List<VO>> selectDataOpt();
}

<select id="selectDataOpt" resultType="VO">
    SELECT ID, NAME, CALL_NUM
    FROM  USER
    ORDER BY INSERTDATE ASC
    LIMIT 100
</select>
```

but mybatis print exception msg that

`org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.TooManyResultsException: Expected one result (or null) to be returned by selectOne(), but found: 21`

What can I do I do not know what I'm missing?

Thank you for reading

Lend your wisdom.

Comment: Why would you ever have an Optional of a List? Just have a List.

Comment: umm  Optional of a List use This will make you clean code. 
Optional.ofNullable(testMapper. selectDataOpt()).orElseGet(Collections::emptyList);

to testMapper. selectDataOpt().orElseGet(Collections::emptyList);

Comment: No, it won't. A list can already be empty. It's completely pointless to wrap it in an optional.

Comment: It's not really pointless: You may wish to say something like `List<Whatever> list = optionalList.orElseThrow(NotFoundException::new);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `Optional`.

Your framework/lib complains about he got too many results from DB but you ask him to compress down to only one (optional) variable.

You just use `Optional` when you expect to get one or no results from DB.

For list, just leave it as it is, most of framework/lib will return an empty list for you.